# Find all the triples $(x,y,z)$ $\in$ $\Bbb R^+_0$ that verifies the following equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Find all the triples $(x,y,z)$  $\in$ $\Bbb R^+_0$ that verifies the next equation system
\begin{align*}
x^2-y &= (z-1)^2\\
y^2-z &= (x-1)^2\\
z^2-x &= (y-1)^2
\end{align*}
**My try**

Adding the 3 equations, expanding the RHS and then substracting terms of the LHS I determinated $x+y+z=3$, so $(1,1,1)$ is a trivial solution, but I don't know a way to find more solutions.

Any help?

Comment: So you found the solution to the given system is that plane. What I don't understand is why you say $\;(1,1,1)\;$ is the only possible solution: also $\;(2,1,0)\,,\,\,or\;\;(-2,4,1)\;$ are in that plane...and they are **not** solutions, so that it cannot be $\;x+y+z=3\;$ is the solution set to the system

Comment: @Fawad first equation

Comment: whoops i forgot to put something i'm gonna edit it right now

Comment: It meant to be positive real numbers

Comment: with 0 included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 
$$y\le x^2\le z^4\le y^8$$

This implies $y\ge 1$.

You can do the same thing for $x$ and $z$.

Then, since $x+y+z=3$, $(1,1,1)$ is the only solution.

Comment: Beat me by a minute :) +1

Comment: Wow, pretty clever, thanks

Comment: This reasoning is valid for non-negative $x,y,z$. I wonder if there are more solutions in $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Any number squared is non-negative, so the right side of those equations are all non-negative.

There-fore, the left-hand sides also have to be non-negative:

$x^2 \ge y$

$y^2 \ge z$

$z^2 \ge x$

Since the numbers themselves are non-negative, on one hand, if $x \le 1$, then $1 \ge x \ge x^2 \ge y \ge y^2 \ge z \ge z^2 \ge x$, which means all three have to be equal to 1.

On the other hand, if $x > 1$, then $z^2 >1$, so $z > 1$, then $y^2 > 1$ and finally $y > 1$, so all three have to be greater than one. Of course, if they are all greater than one they can't sum up to 3, so they have to be equal to one.

Comment: Wow, i liked this explanation i think it is the most clear for me, thanks